# VS2010 output window next message jumping to lines other than warning or error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, build

I'm used to this nice shortcut for jumping to next message in build output window (F4).

But since I migrated to a new PC this shortcut now jumps not only to warnings or errors but also to lines like this:

> 8>  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\PresentationCore.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\PresentationFramework.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Drawing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xaml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\WindowsBase.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize- Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "C:\tmp.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs"

Is there a way to skip these lines, when jumping to next message?

Or do I have to turn these messages off? And how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the MSBuild project build output verbosity from Minimal to Quiet.

`Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run`

[image]

Comment: Thank You. It was set to normal, setting it to minimal solved my problem.